Using Linux server to interconnect 25Gbps and 1Gbps LAN segments
A local network 192.168.1.0/24 that I administrate, was operated at 1Gbps Ethernet. Recently, we got some new switches and machines capable of 25Gbps Ethernet (all DACs). The new 25Gbps switch does not have any 1Gbps port. On one server, I have both 25Gbps NIC and 1Gbps NIC. That is the only device that has access to both segments.
The goal is to keep the network as homogeneous as possible. I do not have any intention to control access between these two segments. I just want to make an extension of the 1Gbps  network and utilize the higher bandwidth wherever it is possible.
My question is: Is it a good idea to utilize the Linux server for this purpose? Would it be enough to create a bridge over those two interfaces? Or is this already a sufficient reason to divide the network into two separate IP networks and route between them? Is there any significant performance penalty for the routing? I will be grateful for any insight.

show the switch names, hardware etc, I still please and beg everyone new to read [ask]

A linux bridge would work of course, but I'd find it rather wasteful to dedicate a server to do that, and not a reasonable architecture to assign this role to a server that already performs some tasks. Bridging networks is a job for a switch. Also, the structure of the L3 depends on application needs. If it's desirable from the user and administration standpoint to split roles between 1G and 25G, split the network and route. (For example, users may go into 25G and printers in 1G, or split between departments/organizational units.)

I agree with @NikitaKipriyanov that a server would be wastefull way of utilising the 25G uplink port. I would rather insert a core switch in the 1G network with several 1G ports and a 25G uplink port in order to maximise throughput to each host in the 1G network. But choose your equipment wisely, because I learned in horror that a certain manufacturer had limited the backplane in a router series to 1G in spite all ports on the router was 2.5G or 10G.

I see and thank you, @NikitaKipriyanov. I just would like to understand better what is the problem with the server doing the bridging. The server is anyway already there and it already provides some essential services for the network (both, 1G and 25G). So what is the disadvantage in assigning it one more role? Actually, all the network is in the racks and I do not have much space for another switch. I can make some but it is getting pretty tight there.

@LasseMichaelMølgaard Thank you for your reply. What do you mean by "a server would be wastefull way of utilising the 25G uplink port"? Would you mind elaborating on it a little bit more, please?

@NikitaKipriyanov, in fact, there is only one significant type of access between the 1G and 25G networks: A storage server is located in the 25G part and I want the 1G machines to access the files (via nfs). There will not be any non-trivial access in the opposite direction. Of course, both segments will communicate with the main server (so far between them). I don't want to limit the bandwidth or increase the latencies for the access to the storage. Is the performance overhead due to routing in any way significant compared to bridging?

It's certainly no worse than software bridging.

@michalt: It is a utization point. 1G to 25G uplink port means 25G uplink port is utilized at most 4% of 25G bandwith is available to per clients on 1G network. If you have a switch with say 24 x 1G port and 1 x 25G uplink port then you can use 96% of bandwith without any client connected to a 1G port on the switch looses bandwith and if you had a 48 x 1G + 1 x 25G (or better 2 x 25G), then it would be an even better situation for 1G network from a bandwith utilisation perspective.

@LasseMichaelMølgaard, thank you so much for this comment. I don't understand how could I have omitted this point. This is very important and I will keep it in mind. Thanks.
